# c# converting a .csv file from Windows UTF-8 to w1252

Tags: c#, csv, utf-8

I need to convert a .csv file from UTF-8 to W1252 (West European).

I have tried the example from the MSDN page and the following code without succes

```
        Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
        //Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        Encoding win1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);


        string src = today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + "-ups.csv";
        string source = File.ReadAllText(src);


        byte[] input = source.ToUTF8ByteArray();
        byte[] output = Encoding.Convert(utf8, win1252, input);

        File.WriteAllText(src + "w1252", win1252.GetString(output));
```

with the extension method

```
   public static class StringHelper
    {
        public static byte[] ToUTF8ByteArray(this string str)
        {
            Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            return encoding.GetBytes(str);
        }
    }
```

After this, the file still reads with broken characters when opened as W1252 and works perfectly if opening with UTF-8, confirming that it is not good.

Thanks!

Comment: "After this, the file still reads with broken characters when opened as W1252" - we don't know what you're using to read it, what those "broken characters" are or what the original correct characters were. Note that not everything that's representable in UTF-8 *can* be represented in Windows-1252. (You're also doing more work than you need to by converting a string back into UTF-8 and then using Encoding.Convert, but that's a different matter.) Fundamentally, there's a lot of information missing in this post.

Comment: Yes, what do you want to happen when the file contains characters that are not in the Windows-1252 character set? Everything might be okay in this sample but not in the next. Users tend to be unhappy when they discover that their data is lost and support trends to be unhappy when they have no idea why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not read in the initial encoding (`Encoding.UTF8`), and write in target one (`Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)`):

```
string fileName = @"C:\MyFile.csv";

File.WriteAllText(fileName, File
  .ReadAllText(fileName, Encoding.UTF8), Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
```

Comment: Good point, I don't know why I was looking so far away. Your solution is working as intended. Thank you!